# Reference request: $L^p$ spaces defined on functions with image in generic metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

A book I'm studying mentions the following: given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, with $P$ probability measure, we define
$$
L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{}, P, X) := \{f: \Omega \to X \, : \, f \text{ is } \mathcal{F}-\mathcal{B}(X)-\text{measurable}, \ \int_\Omega d^p(f, z_0) \, \text{d} P < \infty \text \}
$$
for $z_0 \in X$, endowed with the distance
$$
\delta(f,g) := \left( \int_\Omega d^p(f,g) \, \text{d} P\right)^{1/p}.
$$

This is not necessarely a vector space, but the book claims, without giving a reference, that the completeness of $(X,d)$ implies the completeness of $L^p$ as defined above, as in the more common "vector space case" (and that also other properties are retained). The proof I have in mind of this fact in the classical setting kind of relies on the vector space structure of $L^p$, as the other proofs I've found online.

Could someone please point me to a reference where the spaces $L^p(\Omega, P, X)$ are dealt with? Thanks!

Comment: The proof is exactly the same than proving that $L^p(\mathbb R)$ is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is any good reference for the case of general complete metric spaces, but a lot is known in the case of Banach spaces. When $X$ is a Banach space and $z_0$ is the origin, the classical proof of the completeness the $L^p$ spaces of scalar functions (which, if I remember correctly, consists of showing absolutely convergent series are convergent) can be adapted easily to prove the completeness of $L^p(\Omega,P,X)$ (replace all the absolute values with norms). You can get a short presentation of the "Bochner integral" in the chapter 1 of [this book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-48520-1).

When $X$ is a more general complete metric space, [a theorem of Arens and Eells](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1956.6.397) guarantees that $X$ can be isometrically embedded in a Banach space $F$ in which the image of $z_0$ is the origin.

So by identifying $X$ with a closed (because complete) subset of a Banach space $F$ with $z_0=0$, you can then identify $L^p(\Omega,P,X)$ with the set of (equivalence classes of) functions in $L^p(\Omega,P,F)$ with values in $X$ and showing the completeness of $L^p(\Omega,P,X)$ boils down to showing its closedness in $L^p(\Omega,P,F)$.

But as in the case of scalar functions, convergence in $L^p(\Omega,P,F)$ to some $f\in L^p(\Omega,P,F)$ of a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $L^p(\Omega,P,X)$ implies the existence of a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ which converges $P$-almost surely to $f$, showing that $f$ is in $L^p(\Omega,P,X)$ because $X$ is closed in $F$.